# angularjs filter by an array return all matching results

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I am receiving an array from `$stateParams` that I wish to use to filter the contents of another array. The array contains the `IDs` of a group of exercises. I wish to display the exercise `IDs` that are recovered from the $stateParams.

The `console.log` is giving me a nice `[1,2,3]` array of IDs however I need to filter and show all of the results that match the IDs in the array.

here is the data held in the controller currently for testing.

```
 $scope.exerciseIds = $stateParams.exerciseIds;

 $scope.singleProgrammes = [
 {exerciseId: 1, exerciseName: 'Deadlift', image: 'img/deadlift.png'},
 {exerciseId: 2, exerciseName: 'Squat', image: 'img/squat.png'},
 {exerciseId: 3, exerciseName: 'Lunge', image: 'img/lunge.png'},
 {exerciseId: 4, exerciseName: 'Snatch', image: 'img/snatch.png'},
 {exerciseId: 5, exerciseName: 'Overhead Squat', image: 'img/overhead-squat.png'},
];
```

This is the code from the view:

```
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="programme in programmes| filter:exerciseID" href="#">
```

EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="programme in programmes| filter: filterIds" href="#">
```

And in your controller:

```
// {{x|filter:filterIds}} will run this function once for each item in x
$scope.filterIds = function(item) {
    if ( $stateParams.exerciseIds.indexOf( item.excerciseID ) > -1 ) {
        return true; // the ID is in the array
    } else {
        return false; // the ID is not in the array
    }       
    // Micro version:
    // return ~$stateParams.exerciseIds.indexOf( item.excerciseID );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
      <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="programme in programmes|
               filter:doFilter(item)" href="#">


      $scope.doFilter = function(item) {
          return function(programme) {
      //        if programme.id in your list of ones to display 
      //             return true
      //        else 
      //            return false
          };
      };
```

Comment: Afraid I need a little more help on this one - Please see my edit on how I am getting the $stateParams
Thanks